# How to do pagination in Reactor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

I make repeated paged WebClient requests to a third-party web service. The implementation I have now works *but is blocking*.

My implementation so far:

```
var elementsPerPage = 10;
Flux
    .generate(
        () -> 0,
        (pageIndex, emitter) -> {
            BlahServiceResponse blahServiceResponse =
                webClient
                    .get()
                    .uri("/blah?pageIndex={pageIndex}", pageIndex)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(BlahServiceResponse.class)
                    .block(); // Yuck!!!
            if (blahServiceResponse.getStudents().size() > 0) {
                emitter.next(blahServiceResponse);
            } else {
                emitter.complete();
            }
            return pageIndex + elementsPerPage;
        }
    )
    .subscribe(System.out::println); // Replace me with actual logic
```

For understandable reasons, an "IllegalStateException: The generator didn't call any of the SynchronousSink method" exception is thrown if the code above is changed to the following:

```
webClient
    .get()
    ...
    .bodyToMono(BlahServiceResponse.class)
    .subscribe(emitter::next);
```

So I started looking for an async Sink and [realized it was Flux|MonoSink](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/SynchronousSink.html). But as far as I can see there is no builder method in Flux that supports stateful element generation with Flux|MonoSink.

Am I missing something and is there a more elegant approach to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Static pagination

If you know the page indexes in advance and you have a rule to generate it.

```java
var elementsPerPage = 10;

Flux.generate(
        () -> 0,
        (pageIndex, emitter) -> {
            if (pageIndex < 30) {
                emitter.next(pageIndex);
            } else {
                emitter.complete();
            }
            return pageIndex + elementsPerPage;
        })
        .flatMap(pageIndex -> webClient
                .get()
                .uri("/blah?pageIndex={pageIndex}", pageIndex)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(BlahServiceResponse.class))
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

### Dynamic pagination

If the next page index depends on the last queried page.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    var elementsPerPage = 10;

    callWithPageIndex(0)
            .expand(pagedResponse -> {
                if (pagedResponse.getResponse().isEmpty()) {
                    return Mono.empty();
                } else {
                    return callWithPageIndex(pagedResponse.getPageIndex() + elementsPerPage);
                }
            })
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
}

private static Mono<PagedResponse<BlahServiceResponse>> callWithPageIndex(Integer pageIndex) {
    return webClient
            .get()
            .uri("/blah?pageIndex={pageIndex}", pageIndex)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(BlahServiceResponse.class)
            .map(response -> new PagedResponse<>(pageIndex, response));
}

@lombok.Value
static class PagedResponse<T> {
    int pageIndex;
    T response;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Martin. The decision of whether to produce more elements or not is made from the BlahServiceResponse instance. Have updated the code snippet in my question to reflect this. Given this and your solution, is there a way to signal completion upstream from within the flatMap?

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly.