# Spring WebClient: Call Rest Service which has paginated response

Tags: spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I want to hit a service which has a paginated response using Web Client. ie. I hit a service, check if it returns hasMoreElements as TRUE, then call the service again with updated request parameters like START_ROW, END_ROW, PAGE_NUMBER. What is the best approach to achieve this? Currently am just looping through the results and hitting the service again. But their should be a better approach to this. PFB my pseudocode. Any libraries I can use?

```
boolean hasMoreElements=true;

while(!hasMoreElements==false)
{
response=webClient.post().header(HEADERS).bodyValue(REQUEST).block();
Get the NEW START ROW, END ROW, AND PAGE NUMBER and SET in the REQUEST
Get the hasMoreElements value
}
```

Comment: If your goal is to do it reactively, then you can check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67131903/6051176

Answer (score 0):

Use [JPARepository with paging](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting) for this.

You can return a list of objects and check if its length is less then the limit passed, if yes then you can stop fetching.

You could also return a [Page or a Slice](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-paging/) instead which gives you a little bit more information about the current and next fetch cycle